# How do I multiply values in a query set in django correctly

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to multiply two values in a `queryset` how do I achieve this:
This is what I have :

```
def get_adjustment(self):
        Adjustment.objects.filter(employee_month_id=1,adjustment_type=2)
        .values('exchange_rate','amount').aggregate(Sum('amount', field="exchange_rate*amount")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `F()` objects.

```
.values('exchange_rate','amount').aggregate(Sum(F('amount') * F('exchange_rate')))
```

See the [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/) docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj = SomeModel.objects.filter(**something).extra(
    select = {'total': 'SUM(one_column * another_column)'},
)

Adjustment.objects.filter(employee_month_id=1,adjustment_type=2)
        .values('exchange_rate','amount').extra(select = {'total': 'SUM(exchange_rate * amount)'})
```

Comment: The docs state "Use this method as a last resort" and "This is an old API that we aim to deprecate".